# ruby 2.1 rails 4 sunspot solr tests fail in suite but pass individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, rspec

My team has been stumped on this issue for some time now and are at a loss as to where to try next.  The spec below works correctly when run individually, however, when we run this in our suite via `bundle exec ./bin/rspec spec` these two tests fail every single time:

- GET /external-products/:id/deals
- GET /external-products/search/deals

We have tried numerous different ways to approach this issue and I am starting to suspect something else outside of the said spec. SO I have to turn to the Stack gods, and plea that someone out there has a better approach or even a better question to ask this problem.

Rspec Errors:

```
  8) Retailigence Products and Locations GET /external-products/search/deals Search a given region for related deals by query string
     Failure/Error: expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Integer).at_path('deals/0/id')
     JsonSpec::MissingPath:
       Missing JSON path "deals/0/id"
     # ./spec/features/external_products_spec.rb:151:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  9) Retailigence Products and Locations GET /external-products/:id/deals Search a given region for deals related to a particular product
     Failure/Error: expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Integer).at_path('deals/0/id')
     JsonSpec::MissingPath:
       Missing JSON path "deals/0/id"
     # ./spec/features/external_products_spec.rb:105:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is our spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'email_spec'
require 'pry'
require 'rspec_api_documentation/dsl'
require 'sunspot/rails/spec_helper'
require 'sunspot_test/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/concerns/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }


# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

# Model specs: type: :model
# Controller specs: type: :controller
# Request specs: type: :request
# Feature specs: type: :feature
# View specs: type: :view
# Helper specs: type: :helper
# Mailer specs: type: :mailer
# Routing specs: type: :routing

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.order = 'random'
  config.seed = srand % 0xFFFF
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.before(:each) { GC.disable }
  config.after(:each) { GC.enable }

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include JsonSpec::Helpers
  config.include Stubs
  config.include LoginHelper
  config.include SolrSpecHelper
  config.include SunspotMatchers
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller

  config.before do
    Sunspot.session = SunspotMatchers::SunspotSessionSpy.new(Sunspot.session)
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

RspecApiDocumentation.configure do |config|
  config.format = :json
end
```

The features/external_product_service_spec.rb

```
resource 'Retailigence Products and Locations', type: :feature, api: true, slow: true, sunspot: true do
  before(:all) do
    log_in_as_client!
  end

  let(:id) { '7c381d47-d251-457a-a2d2-930c8993a5fa' }
  let(:lat) { 39.74585 }
  let(:long) { -104.998929 }
  let(:q) { 'whiteboard cleaner' }

  get '/external-products/:id' do
    parameter :id, 'The external id to search', required: true
    parameter :lat, 'The latitude to search', required: true
    parameter :long, 'The longitude to search', required: true
    parameter :radius, 'The radius, in miles, to search'

    example 'Search a given region for products matching a given external product id' do
      do_request user_email: @user.email, user_token: @token, timestamp: @timestamp

      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Array).at_path('external_products')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/id')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/name')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/seo_slug')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/description')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Array).at_path('external_products/0/images')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/price')
    end
  end

  get '/external-products/:id/external-stores' do
    parameter :id, 'The external id to search', required: true
    parameter :lat, 'The latitude to search', required: true
    parameter :long, 'The longitude to search', required: true
    parameter :radius, 'The radius, in miles, to search'

    example 'Search a given region for stores which have the product matching a given external product id' do
      do_request user_email: @user.email, user_token: @token, timestamp: @timestamp

      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Array).at_path('external_stores')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_stores/0/id')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_stores/0/name')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_stores/0/store_logo')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Float).at_path('external_stores/0/longitude')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Float).at_path('external_stores/0/latitude')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Float).at_path('external_stores/0/distance')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_stores/0/city')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_stores/0/address')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_stores/0/zip')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_stores/0/state')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_stores/0/phone_number')
    end
  end

  get '/external-products/search' do
    parameter :q, 'The query string to search', required: true
    parameter :lat, 'The latitude to search', required: true
    parameter :long, 'The longitude to search', required: true
    parameter :radius, 'The radius, in miles, to search'

    example 'Search a given region for products by query string' do
      do_request q: q, user_email: @user.email, user_token: @token, timestamp: @timestamp

      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Array).at_path('external_products')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/id')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/name')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/seo_slug')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/description')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Array).at_path('external_products/0/images')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('external_products/0/price')
    end
  end

  get '/external-products/:id/deals' do
    before(:each) do
      solr_setup
      store.location.save
      store.location.reload
      store.location.index!
    end

    let(:retailer) { create :retailer }
    let!(:deal) { create :deal, retailer_id: retailer.id }
    let!(:store) do
      create :store, retailer_id: retailer.id,
             location: (create :location, latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    end
    let!(:retailigence_retailer) do
      create :retailigence_retailers_retailer, retailer_id: retailer.id,
             retailigence_retailer_id: '39bfd9a5-f979-4ef1-816b-f9a38093494a'
    end
    let!(:content_location) do
      create :content_location, store_id: store.id,
             locatable_id: deal.id, locatable_type: 'Deal'
    end

    parameter :id, 'The external id to search', required: true
    parameter :lat, 'The latitude to search', required: true
    parameter :long, 'The longitude to search', required: true
    parameter :radius, 'The radius, in miles, to search'

    example 'Search a given region for deals related to a particular product' do
      do_request id: id, user_email: @user.email, user_token: @token, timestamp: @timestamp

      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Array).at_path('deals')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Integer).at_path('deals/0/id')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Integer).at_path('deals/0/retailer_id')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/title')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/seo_slug')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/name')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/sort_name')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/description')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(:boolean).at_path('deals/0/is_local')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(:boolean).at_path('deals/0/is_featured')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Array).at_path('images')
    end
  end

  get '/external-products/search/deals' do
    before(:each) do
      solr_setup
      store.location.save
      store.location.reload
      store.location.index!
    end

    let(:retailer) { create :retailer }
    let!(:deal) { create :deal, retailer_id: retailer.id }
    let!(:store) do
      create :store, retailer_id: retailer.id,
             location: (create :location, latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    end
    let!(:retailigence_retailer) do
      create :retailigence_retailers_retailer, retailer_id: retailer.id,
             retailigence_retailer_id: 'eea1722b-ac89-4cce-95ec-26c2414646d7'
    end
    let!(:content_location) do
      create :content_location, store_id: store.id,
             locatable_id: deal.id, locatable_type: 'Deal'
    end

    parameter :q, 'The query string to search', required: true
    parameter :lat, 'The latitude to search', required: true
    parameter :long, 'The longitude to search', required: true
    parameter :radius, 'The radius, in miles, to search'

    example 'Search a given region for related deals by query string' do
      do_request q: q, lat: lat, long: long,
                 user_email: @user.email, user_token: @token, timestamp: @timestamp

      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Array).at_path('deals')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Integer).at_path('deals/0/id')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Integer).at_path('deals/0/retailer_id')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/title')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/seo_slug')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/name')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/sort_name')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(String).at_path('deals/0/description')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(:boolean).at_path('deals/0/is_local')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(:boolean).at_path('deals/0/is_featured')
      expect(response_body).to have_json_type(Array).at_path('images')
    end
  end
end
```

The retailigence_service.rb:

```
class RetailigenceService
  NEGATIVE_KEYWORDS = 'AND !DVD AND !CD AND !"compact disc"'
  MAX_QUERY_TIME = 5000

  attr_accessor :products, :locations, :params

  def self.products(params = {})
    fetch(params).products
  end

  def self.locations(params = {})
    fetch_locations(params).locations
  end

  def self.fetch(params = {})
    service = new
    service.fetch(params)
    service
  end

  def self.fetch_locations(params = {})
    service = new
    service.fetch_locations(params)
    service
  end

  def fetch(params = {})
    @params = { offset: 0, limit: 25 }.merge(params)
    @params.symbolize_keys!

    search_result = Retailigence::Product.search(search_params)
    @products = search_result.results
    build_products
  rescue Retailigence::NoResults
    @products = []
  rescue Retailigence::APIException
    @products = []
  end

  def fetch_locations(params = {})
    @params = { offset: 0, limit: 25 }.merge(params)
    @params.symbolize_keys!

    Rails.logger.debug "[SENDING] #{location_params}"

    search_result = Retailigence::Location.search(location_params)
    @locations = search_result.results.map { |retailer| retailer.locations }.flatten
    build_locations
  rescue Retailigence::NoResults
    @locations = []
  rescue Retailigence::APIException
    @locations = []
  end

  private

  def keywords
    keywords = @params[:keywords] || ''
    keywords << ' ' << NEGATIVE_KEYWORDS
    keywords.gsub(/^\ AND\ /, '')
  end

  def page_size
    @params[:limit]
  end

  def page
    (@params[:offset] / @params[:limit]) + 1
  end

  def location_params
    {
      userlocation: @params[:userlocation],
      requestorid: RETAILIGENCE_REQUESTOR_ID,
      productid: @params[:productid],
      pagesize: page_size,
      page: page,
      maxquerytime: MAX_QUERY_TIME,
      excludeadultcontent: true
    }
  end

  def search_params
    search_params = {
      userlocation: @params[:userlocation],
      requestorid: RETAILIGENCE_REQUESTOR_ID,
      pagesize: page_size, page: page,
      maxquerytime: MAX_QUERY_TIME,
      excludeadultcontent: true
    }

    search_params[:keywords] = keywords unless @params[:product_id]
    search_params[:productid] = @params[:product_id] if @params[:product_id]
    search_params
  end

  def format_price_prefix(prefix)
    prefix = '$' if prefix == 'USD'
    prefix
  end

  def build_products
    @products.map! do |p|
      p.images ||= []
      p.description_long ||= ''
      RetailigenceProduct.new(
        id: p.id, name: p.name, seo_slug: p.name.slugify,
        description: p.description_long,
        images: p.images.map { |img| img.link },
        price: "#{format_price_prefix p.msrp_currency}#{p.price}",
        retailigence_retailer_id: p.location.retailer.id)
    end
  end

  def build_locations
    @locations.map! do |l|
      RetailigenceLocation.new(
        id: l.id, name: l.retailer.name,
        latitude: l.latitude, longitude: l.longitude,
        phone_number: l.phone, address: l.address.address1,
        city: l.address.city, state: l.address.state,
        zip: l.address.postal, store_logo: l.retailer.logo,
        distance: l.distance.distance)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is our Sunspot setup in support/sunspot.rb:

```
$original_sunspot_session = Sunspot.session
Sunspot.session = Sunspot::Rails::StubSessionProxy.new($original_sunspot_session)

module SolrSpecHelper

  def solr_setup
    unless $sunspot
      $sunspot = Sunspot::Rails::Server.new

      pid = fork do
        STDERR.reopen('/dev/null')
        STDOUT.reopen('/dev/null')
        $sunspot.run
      end
      # shut down the Solr server
      at_exit { Process.kill('TERM', pid) }
      # wait for solr to start
      sleep 5
    end

    Sunspot.session = $original_sunspot_session
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify how the two specs are failing?

Comment: @fivedigit I have added the specific error message we are getting from rspec.  do you have any tips?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered this exact problem before, however I have two suggestions/recommendations that may be helpful to those who encounter it in the future.  Please comment if you find it successful or unsuccessful.

1. While less than ideal you can remove the 'spring' gem from your test group of your Gemfile if it has been included there.
2. Try running `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to "springify" the executables in your `bin/` directory.